# overloading >> in class with instream

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i have the following code:

```
class someclass
{
     private :
     unsinged char a; 
     public :
      ...
}
```

I want to use

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in,  someclass &x)
{
    in>>x.a;
    return in;
}

int main()
{
  someclass test;
 std::cin>>test;
 return 0;
}
```

My problem is that, as a user, I want to insert an integer between 0-255. However, it only accepts single chars. How am I supposed to "cast" it to integers only?

Thank you.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How am I supposed to "cast" it to integers only?

Use a temporary integer for input then:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in,  someclass &x)
{
    int temp;
    if(!(in>>temp) || temp < 0 || temp > 255) 
        { throw std::runtime_error("Invalid input"); }
    x.a = (unsigned char)temp;
    return in;
}
```